# Facet_grid with all panels with a free_y

Tags: ggplot2, facet, facet-grid

I have a 6x6 grid (sites along the side and year along the top), showing abundance (y) over time(x).

I have used `facet_grid` to build the plot, using `free_y`. This has plotted a figure with each row having a shared y axis. I need to have a `free_y` for all the panels individually and I know that `facet_grid` doesnt allow this, while `facet_wrap` does. I would like to use `facet_grid` becuase it keeps the order of the panels, with columns for each year, and rows for each site.

I've tried using the `lemon` package with the `facet_rep_grid` function but this hasn't worked. Does anyone know how I can `free_y` across all the panels seperately?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

facet_wrap does this, and is what I use, although it does mean you have the faceting value as a title for each individual facet, which can be a pain.

```
  ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = as.factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(year ~ drv,
             scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to use `ggh4x::facet_grid2()` to set independent y scales. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x). Example with standard dataset below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = as.factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(vars(year), vars(drv), 
                     scales = "free_y", independent = "y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you that worked well. But the next step in my code doesn't work. Would you be able to suggest how to adjust it so it works with your package? The aim is to remove the empty (no data) panels.

Comment: ``` myplot2 <-
myplot %>%
  # Generate gtable of ggplot object
  ggplot2::ggplot_build() %>% ggplot2::ggplot_gtable() %>%
  # Modify gtable by filtering out grobs based on name using a regex pattern
  # $ represents end of string. Otherwise 'panel-1-1' removes 'panel-1-10', too.
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-1-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
  gtable::gtable_filter(pattern = "panel-3-1$", invert = TRUE) %>%
    # Plot the modified gtable
  {grid::grid.newpage(); grid::grid.draw(myplot)} ```

Comment: apologies I'm not sure why it isnt shown as code

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be `facet_rep_grid` in the `lemon` package.

Sample code:

```
   #install.packages("lemon")
library(lemon)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(x=time, y=abundance, color=sites))+
  lemon::facet_rep_grid(year~sites, 
                   scales="free",
                   repeat.tick.labels = "all")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(size=0.5))+
  labs(x="Time", y="Abundance", fill="Sites")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Plot:

[image]